# Кто нибудь работал с Libreoffice SDK v7.6 и .Net6 и выше?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, libre-office

Есть проблема, которую давным-давно будируют в сети: Ошибка `uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();`
При вызове `XComponentContext context= uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();` в C# коде, если всё это собирается через проект visualStudio в .NET6(and more). В Net Framework 4.xxx тот же код прекрасно собирается и работает.

При этом make собирает работающие примеры с компилятором от той же студии, работающие в том же .NET6. У кого-нибудь есть опыт работы этим СДК под VisualStudio? А VisualStudioCode?
Взгляд в Make-файл вызывает подозрение на неразрешённую ссылку внутри библиотек где-то при загрузке сборки.

Добавлю: GNU-тым make пример собирается и работает. Из той же cmd- сессии VisialStudio собирает нерабочий проект. :-(
Заранее благодарен за ответы на вопрос.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)